EURIBOR vanilla swaptions are in fact slightly-mid-curve swaptions
EURIBOR swaptions have their underlying swaps starting 2 business days after the expiry of the swaption, and are therefore slightly "mid-curve". How does the market take this into account (for a quick pricing formula), especially the practionners who calibrate models on swaption volatilities ?

I don;t think this is true since a spot starting swap also starts 2 days later than trade date

You don't think that what is true ? If a spot starting swap starts 2 days later than the trade day, the spot starting swap that we'll enter in at expiry will also start 2 day later than the expiry, hence the swaption will be mid-curve slightly. Do I miss something ?

I guess that my question is equivalent to the following : "how is a swap rate computed when there's a lag between the trade date and the start date ?" I realize that I know how it is computed when there's no lag (you suppose the swap value to be zero at the trade date) but that I don't know what's done when start = trade + 2bd.

I posted https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/80095/how-is-swap-rate-calculated-for-a-vanilla-swap-when-there-is-a-lag-between-the-t
