How is swap rate calculated for a vanilla swap when there is a lag between the trade date and the start date
Take a vanilla EURIBOR swap and suppose that the start date of the swap is equal to the trade date. To compute the swap rate, you say that the value of the swap at the trade date must be zero, which finally gives you the following expression of the swap rate :
$$s_{T_{trade}} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^N \delta_j^{fl} P_{T_j^{fl}}^{disc} L_{T_{trade}}^{[T_{j-1}^{fl}, T_{j}^{fl}]}}{\sum_{i=1}^M \delta_i^{fix} P_{T_i^{fix}}^{disc}}$$
where $P_t^{disc}$ is the value (at trade date $T_{trade}$) of the discount curve zero-coupon and where the $T_j^{fl}$ dates of the floating leg and the $T_i^{fix}$ dates of the fixed leg are computed from the trade date $T_{trade}$, such that $T_{trade} = T_0^{fl} = T_0^{fix}$. The computation is simple : the present value of the fixed leg is the swap strike time the annuity which is the denominator in the previous expression, while the present value of the floating leg is equal to the numerator of the previous expression, as each $L_{t}^{[T_{j-1}^{fl}, T_{j}^{fl}]}$ is a martingale under the $T_j^{fl}$-forward measure.
How is the swap rate computed and how does the previous computation change when the start date $T_{start}$ of the swap is equal to the trade date plus two business days (which is the convention for EURIBOR swaps) so that $T_{start} = T_0^{fl} = T_0^{fix} > T_{trade}$ ?

I'd say that you use the exact same methodology, but shift all dates accordingly. The resulting swap rate will be (slightly) different, of course.

"Shift all dates accordingly" : you mean I discount up to the trade date and not up to the start date ?

For calculating the swap mid-market rate it doesn't actually matter whether you discount to the trade date or to today. The sum of the both legs should be zero in both cases so the presence of an additional scaling factor is moot.
